# Тело в http ответе приходит только после множества запросов

Tags: c++, linux, http

```
#include "iostream"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "tools.h"//мой файл. там strlen() и ip2int()
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(80);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip2int(192,168,0,1));
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr);
  char result[1024];
  char request_buffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";//Это исправлено
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    write(sockfd,request_buffer,strlen(request_buffer));
  }
  read(sockfd, result, 1024);
  cout << result << endl;
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Тело приходит если посылать запросы по несколько раз. С первого раза приходят только заголовки с пустым телом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправляйте два раза символы новой строки:
`"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"`

Дело в том, что по [спецификации HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) окончание запроса — \r\n после пустой строки, то есть \r\n\r\n. Это сделано для возможности отсылать заголовки запроса. Например:

```
(request)
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com

(response)
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: server version
    Date: date
    ...
    
    <HTML>
    ...
```

Попробуйте телнетом на 80-й порт — станет совсем понятно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int status;

  status = 0;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(80);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
  char result[1025];
  char request_buffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n";
  write(sockfd,request_buffer,strlen(request_buffer));
  while (status = read (sockfd, result, 1024)) {
      printf ("=============== READ STATUS %d =============\n", status);
      printf ("%s\n", result);
      memset (&result, 0, sizeof (result));
  }
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Я бы не стал тащить всю плюсплюсную тяжесть ради одного только `cout`.

Comment: Спасибо, в телнет все работает, но в программе изменилось лишь то, что исчезла ошибка 408. Тело все так же приходит лишь при многократных запросах

Comment: А покажите полностью актуальный код вместе с установкой соединения (адрес не обязательно), а то я вот смотрю на отсылку запроса в цикле и не очень понимаю, о чём мы разговариваем :)

Comment: Добавил полностью код

Comment: Поправил немного у себя (всё равно функции надо было додумывать). Работает.

Comment: Хм, не знал что эта так работает) Но все равно почему то не доходит все тело. бывает прочтет 1.5к символов и потом возвращает -1. Хотя в content-length=6353. Но это как я понял, запрашивать, пока не соберется? Или изменить условие в while, на то, пока content-length не станет равна сумме частей?

Comment: Нет. Читать man read и смотреть, во что устанавливается errno при возврате -1. Но тут я уже не помощник.